Docker container cant connect with mongoDb
Issue Summary: I'm encountering a connection error between my Spring Boot application and a MongoDB database running in separate Docker containers.
Error Description: I'm receiving the following error:
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

This indicates that my Spring Boot application is unable to connect to the MongoDB server.
Root Cause: The MongoDB server might not be running or isn't accessible at the specified host and port (mongodb_instance:27017).
application.properties
# Local MongoDB configuration
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydatabase

application.yml (I think in this file I have a mistake)
spring:
  profiles:
    active: docker

  data:
    mongodb:
      host: mongodb_instance 
      port: 27017
      database: mydatabase  

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb_instance
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - backend

  spring-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

dockerfile
# Use an appropriate base image for your Java application
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim AS build

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Maven wrapper script and pom.xml to the container
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY src src

# Make the Maven wrapper executable
RUN chmod +x mvnw

# Build your application with Maven
RUN ./mvnw clean package -DskipTests

# Stage 2: Use a smaller base image for runtime
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the built artifact from the build stage
COPY --from=build /app/target/simple-spring-mongodb-backup-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar

# Expose the port your application runs on
EXPOSE 8080

# Specify the command to run your application
CMD ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker", "-jar", "./app.jar"]

I tried everything possible but no solution yet, I tried with
spring:
  profiles:
    active: docker

  data:
    mongodb:
      host: 172.17.0.2  # Replace with the IP address of your MongoDB container
      port: 27017
      database: mydatabase  # Replace with your actual database name

this config also but nothing works

If you are sure the container is up and running, try telnet to the mongodb container. Also check if your firewall is blocking the port.

yes I did telnet mongosh --host 172.18.0.2 --port 27017. Its same timeout issue

then either your container is not running or your firewall is blocking.

Are both the application.yml and application.properties file built into the jar file?  Are you sure Spring is seeing the one you intend?  I might add a Compose-level setting environment: { SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST: mongodb } to override this with the Compose-specific host name at deploy time.

Thank you so much everyone. Now it is running so far. But I am adding a cron job now, that it will do automatic backup in every 2 min. But that cron job file is not executed I dont know why. Here you find the code Should I add any dependency or anything to run a cron?  https://notepad.pw/pratik1234

@DavidMaze  There is a minor problem, though I create two profile but I found it always try to run docker config even if it is in localhost..
